# Maven: How to allow a certain OS for build?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I know I can require specific OS family using `maven-enforcer-plugin` like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>check-os</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireOS>
                        <family>unix</family>
                        <message>
                            You should use Unix to build this.
                        </message>
                    </requireOS>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But can I define multiple OS (for example Unix and Windows) that can be used for build?

Can't find any straight way to do it, so I appreciate any workaround.

Comment: I found nothing about configuring a rule for multiple OS or combined rules. But it is possible to write own rules with any desired parameters or parameter lists:
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goal of the `<requireOS>` element is to make some instruction during build **platform-dependent**, i.e. you need to perform some action based on the current operation system, thus it won't make much sense if you define configure some plugins for some OS and discard others.

In that spirit, the `<requireOS>` does not allow for range restriction (you cannot define multiple OSs as: `<requireOS>[windows,linux]</requireOS>`).

Meanwhile you still can write your own custom rule inheriting the `EnforcerRule` and only make the build fail if the current Operating System is not into your **custom rule required OSs range**.

There is already an implemented a rule that I have used once. You can check the [*multiple-os-enforcer-rule* project URL](https://github.com/wisebrains/multiple-os-enforcer-rule) where you can find more details on how-to use the custom rule.

More on custom rules implementation can be found in the [Maven Docs](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use profiles to manage different OS

Eg :

```
<profiles>
<profile>
  <id>exec-windows</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>windows</family>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <build> <plugins> ....
```

Comment: Yeah, but as I understand I easily can restrict some OS for build in this way. When I want to allow a couple OS, I need to declare all OS that cannot be used in this section. Correct?